# What is "disclosure by transmission"?

Tags: gdpr

Article 4(2) GDPR states:

> ‘processing’ means any operation or set of operations which is performed on personal data or on sets of personal data, whether or not by automated means, such as collection, recording, organisation, structuring, storage, adaptation or alteration, retrieval, consultation, use, **disclosure by transmission**, dissemination or otherwise making available, alignment or combination, restriction, erasure or destruction;

What exactly is "disclosure by transmission"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means sending the data to someone else e.g. in an email.